# Change the highlighted color of angular material input text box

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, material-ui

Hi I am using angular material, I like to change the material input focus color on click

Right now by default it is showing in purple color, I like to change white color

[image]

I tried with lot of css. But nothing is working for me

Below is the example of stackblitz URL

https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-input-sample?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Do you want to change theme or single input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the css of the mat-input elements by using ::ng-deep.

```
::ng-deep {
  .mat-form-field-label {
    color: white !important;
  }

  .mat-form-field.mat-focused .mat-form-field-ripple {
    background-color: white !important;
  }
}
```

[Example in stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-input-sample-h35zah?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.scss)

Comment: Please note ::ng-deep is depracated